# jQuery next() and/or remove() breaking in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've got this silly problem (called Internet Explorer) that keeps breaking on something that no other browser has a problem with. Since this is pretty common ground, I thought I'd ask.

If I try to run this line through IE8:

```
$('#map').next('.point').remove();
```

I get nothing. If I completely remove the line, my little popups show up and begin to stack their contents together in the box (which is why I need to remove a `div` with a class called `point`.

I know IE has a history of off behavior with both `.next()` and `.remove()`, and I figure it has to do with `.point` not existing on first click (Perhaps IE is hung up on removing something that doesn't exist?). I've tried setting conditions for that to even be called, and it still breaks. Any clue what I can do?

Comment: To eliminate the possibility of `.point` not existing: `$point = $('#map').next('.point'); $point.length && $point.remove();`

Comment: No, not that then... Since that does work, however, in every other browser, I'll keep it in. You can view the actual project, if it helps, at http://ocbujinkan.com/Test/map/

Comment: do you have a [fiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/Litote0707/5npGM/). this fiddle works in IE, though if you click the button too fast, `remove` doesn't happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is not the JavaScript but the CSS. If you inspect the page in IE, the div.point is being created correctly but not being displayed. In FireFox the div.point element gets an inline style of display:block but that inline style is not applied in IE. You can use Firebug to see that in Firefox and the IE developer tools (F12).

Change the .point style in your css from display:none to display: block and you should see the box.

Comment: Awesome. I couldn't even see anything happening with the bloody IE dev tools. Useless load they are. That fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with your site, it looks to me like your problem is that `.fadeIn()` is not working, for whatever reason. If you call `.show()` instead, it works. If I load a newer version of jQuery on your site, `.fadeIn()` works as well.  Are you stuck with 1.4.2, or can you upgrade?

Comment: Sounds like the same problem as @phil mccull was describing – This version has some issue with not setting the `display:block` property on IE. Microsoft has taught me though: never try to upgrade yourself out of a problem.